# how could I evaluate this integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{\sin^2{x}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

First, I break the integral apart then get:
$$\int\frac{1-\cos^2{x}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$
I know how to calculate $$\int\frac{1}{1+e^x}\,dx$$ but not $$\int\frac{\cos^2{x}}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

can anyone give me a hint to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to evaluate the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{1+e^x}\,dx$ for some value of $a$? If so, there is in fact a way to do this.

Comment: @JimmyK4542. Could you go ahead ? I am very interested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $I$ be the integral. Substitute $-x$ for $x$ to get $I = \displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{1+e^{-x}}\,dx = \int_{-a}^{a}\dfrac{e^x\sin^2 x}{e^x+1}\,dx$. Now, add the result to the original integral to get $2I = \displaystyle\int_{-a}^{a}\sin^2 x\,dx$, which is easy to compute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no elementary antiderivative. The best you can do is to write it in terms of hypergeometric functions.  See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20Sin[x]%5E2%2F%281%2BExp[x]%29).

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Israel answered, there is no way to get something simple (remember that hypergoemtric functions corresponds to infinite sums).

If you need to compute the integral, you can perform a Taylor expansion of the integrand and integrate each term; this would give for example $$\int\frac{\sin^2{x}}{1+e^x}\,dx=\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{16}-\frac{x^5}{30}+\frac{5
   x^6}{288}+\frac{x^7}{315}-\frac{29 x^8}{11520}-\frac{x^9}{5670}+\frac{127
   x^{10}}{483840}+\frac{x^{11}}{155925}-\frac{691
   x^{12}}{29030400}-\frac{x^{13}}{6081075}+O\left(x^{14}\right)$$ Suppose that the integration has to be done $0$ and $1$; the exact value is close to $0.08892217$ while the above expansion yields to $0.08892025$.

Answer (score 0):

> *How could I evaluate this integral ?*

[You](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) [can't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). Even its definite equivalent does not possess a particularly interesting closed form:

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{1+e^x}dx=\frac{\ln2}2+\frac{\psi_0\bigg(\dfrac12+i\bigg)+\psi_0\bigg(\dfrac12-i\bigg)}8-\frac{\psi_0\big(1+i\big)+\psi_0\big(1-i\big)}8$$

If there would have been a minus sign in each of the two numerators above, we could have easily applied the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) for the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), but, as it stands, our hands are tied. The above expression was obtained by using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) along with the simple substitution $u=e^x$ to rewrite the integral in terms of [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), and then employing the [relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers) between the latter and the afore-mentioned [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Answer (score 0):

$\int\dfrac{\sin^2x}{1+e^x}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1-\cos2x}{2(1+e^x)}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1}{2(1+e^x)}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2(1+e^x)}dx$

Case $1$: $x\leq0$

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{2(1+e^x)}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2(1+e^x)}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{e^{-x}}{2(e^{-x}+1)}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{nx}\cos2x}{2}dx$

$=-\int\dfrac{d(e^{-x}+1)}{2(e^{-x}+1)}-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{nx}\cos2x}{2}dx$

$=-\dfrac{\ln(e^{-x}+1)}{2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{nx}(2\sin2x+n\cos2x)}{2(n^2+4)}+C$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

Case $2$: $x\geq0$

Then $\int\dfrac{1}{2(1+e^x)}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2(1+e^x)}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{e^{-x}}{2(e^{-x}+1)}dx-\int\dfrac{e^{-x}\cos2x}{2(e^{-x}+1)}dx$

$=-\int\dfrac{d(e^{-x}+1)}{2(e^{-x}+1)}-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{-(n+1)x}\cos2x}{2}dx$

$=-\dfrac{\ln(e^{-x}+1)}{2}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^ne^{-(n+1)x}(2\sin2x-(n+1)\cos2x)}{2((n+1)^2+4)}+C$ (can be obtained from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)